# Is every integer $z$ representable in Pell form as $x^2 \pm dy^2 =z$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

We know that there are integers that cannot be represented as the sum of two squares (Fermat's Four Square Theorem).

We also know that every natural number can be represented as the sum of four squares (Lagrange's Four Square Theorem).

Is every integer $z$ representable in Pell form as $x^2 \pm dy^2 = z$, with $d$ being a square-free integer with $|d| > 1$? $d$ is not fixed and cannot be equal to $z$ (since $x=0, y=1, d=z$ would be a trivial solution). Similarly, $x^2$ can be taken to be any square and $y = 1$ and $d = \pm(z - x^2)$ would be a trivial solution.

So, the question is are there any non-trivial solutions $(x, y, d)$ for the equation $x^2 \pm dy^2 = z$?

In other words, I am looking for representing $z$ as the sum (or difference) of a square and $d$ repetitions of a square.

Notes:

- $d = 1$ is the Two Square Theorem and $d = -1$ is the factorization of $z$
- $d$ is required to be square-free as the equation would reduce to the Two Squares form otherwise

Comment: For any solution $z$ should be a quadratic residue modulo $d$. This is false in general, for example, it's false when $d$ is prime of the form $4k+3$ and $z\equiv -1\pmod p$.

Comment: Is $d$ fixed here?  If not, then of course every natural number can be written as $dn^2$ where $d$ is square free. If $d$ is fixed, then, e.g., $5$ can't be written as $m^2+2n^2$

Comment: @lulu: d is not fixed. So, z could be a quadratic residue modulo d.

Comment: If $z=r s^2$ with $r$ squarefree, let $d=r$, $y=s$, and $x=0$ assuming $r \neq 1$. If $z$ is squarefree let $d=z$, $y=1$, and $x=0$

Comment: It's a more interesting problem if you fix $d$

Comment: @vvgirl.  I don't understand.  If you can vary $d$, then the problem is trivial, no?

Comment: @RyanShesler: You are fixing z to have a structure and I get that solves it for the class of integers that have that structure. The question is for general z.

Comment: @vvgiri All integers can be expressed as $rs^2$ with $r$ squarefree

Comment: Hmm.. @RyanShesler: You are right. I should probably clarify the question. I am looking for sufficiently large z and non-trivial solutions x,y are both not zero simultaneously and d != z. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I just realized that it is indeed trivial to get solutions $(x, y, d)$. We could just start with a trivial solution and compose them to get other solutions. So, it is indeed true that we can represent all integers in the Pell form $x^2 \pm dy^2 = z$. @RyanShesler, I feel your comments helped in coming to this conclusion. If you want to edit a complete response, I will go ahead and accept it.

Comment: @vvgiri I've written up an answer summarizing the ideas presented here. It is not quite complete, perhaps you can complete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me paraphrase your question as follows:

> Determine all $z\in\Bbb{Z}$ for which there exist $d,x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $|d|,|y|>1$ and $d$ squarefree such that
> $$x^2+dy^2=z.\tag{1}$$

First note that for $z=0$ there are *no* integral solutions with $d$ squarefree.

If $z\neq0$ then for every integer $x$ we have the trivial solution
$$(d,x,y)=(z-x^2,x^2,1),$$
which of course fails to meet the condition that $|y|>1$. But for sufficiently large values of $x$ we get
$$d=z-x^2<-1,$$
and so $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ is a real quadratic ring. By Dirichlet's unit theorem its unit group has rank $1$, so if $u+v\sqrt{-d}\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ is a fundamental unit and $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ is any integer we have
$$N\left((x+y\sqrt{-d})(u+v\sqrt{-d})^n\right)=N(x+y\sqrt{-d})N(u+v\sqrt{-d})^n=z,$$
yielding infinitely many integral solutions to $(1)$: If $a_n,b_n\in\Bbb{Z}$ are such that
$$a_n+b_n\sqrt{-d}=(x+y\sqrt{-d})(u+v\sqrt{-d})^n,$$
then the above shows that indeed
$$a_n^2+db_n^2=z.$$
Moreover, this yields infinitely many integral solutions $(d,x,y)=(d,a_n,b_n)$ with $|y|>1$, because if $b_m=b_n$ then it quickly follows that $m=n$.

All that remains to be shown is that we can choose $x$ sufficiently large such that $d=z-x^2$ is squarefree.